# Show/Hide (Toggle) a Fixed Element Depending on Other Elements When Scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, scroll

Is there a way to toggle between showing and hiding a fixed element based on the elements it passes when scrolling vertically?

Here is a visual reference of what I'm looking to achieve:

[image]

I would prefer for this to function to detect the fixed element's position on a page, rather than the window's scroll position.

Hopefully the photo is explanatory enough; otherwise, please check the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var div2 = $('#div2');
  var div1 = $('#div1');
  var div1_top = div1.offset().top;
  var div1_height = div1.height();
  var div1_bottom = div1_top + div1_height;
  console.log(div1_bottom);
  $window.on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var viewport_height = $window.height();
    var scrollTop_bottom = scrollTop + viewport_height;
    div2.toggleClass('show', scrollTop > div1_top && (scrollTop + window.innerHeight) < div1_bottom);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccffcc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#div1 {
  background: #0099ff;
  height: 1500px;
  color: #fff;
}

#div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ffff00;
  color: #000;
  display: none;
}

#div2.show {
  display: block;
}

#div3 {
  height: 1500px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br> Scroll area before <b>div1</b> appears
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">This is <b>div2</b></div>
  This is <b>div1</b>
  <br>
  <i>(Toggle show/hide <b>div2</b> when the top of <b>div2</b> passes the top of <b>div1</b>)</i>
</div>
<div id="div3">
  This is <b>div3</b>
  <br>
  <i>(Toggle show/hide <b>div2</b> when the bottom of <b>div2</b> reaches the top of <b>div3</b>)</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

If yes, the solution is that you should consider the distance of the window's top to #div2(the center part)

**Edited**

Add the feature that the comments metioned

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var div2 = $('#div2');
  var div1 = $('#div1');
  $window.on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    var viewport_height = $window.height();
    var scrollTop_bottom = scrollTop + viewport_height;
    var window_top_to_div2 = ($window.height()-div2.height())/2;
    
    
    var div1_top = div1.offset().top;
    var div1_height = div1.height();
    var div1_bottom = div1_top + div1_height;
  
    div2.toggleClass('show', scrollTop >= (div1_top-window_top_to_div2) && (scrollTop + window.innerHeight) <= (div1_bottom+window_top_to_div2));
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccffcc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#div1 {
  background: #0099ff;
  height: 1500px;
  color: #fff;
}

#div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #ffff00;
  color: #000;
  display: none;
}

#div2.show {
  display: block;
}

#div3 {
  height: 1500px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br> Scroll area before <b>div1</b> appears
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">This is <b>div2</b></div>
  This is <b>div1</b>
  <br>
  <i>(Toggle show/hide <b>div2</b> when the top of <b>div2</b> passes the top of <b>div1</b>)</i>
</div>
<div id="div3">
  This is <b>div3</b>
  <br>
  <i>(Toggle show/hide <b>div2</b> when the bottom of <b>div2</b> reaches the top of <b>div3</b>)</i>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I was curious to know also if this function would work for a circumstance where `#div1`'s height was variable based on the content inside of it, (instead of a static `1500px`).

Comment: It's OK that #div1 's height is dynamic, but you should put div1_top and div1_bottom in the scroll event handler to make it dynamic.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. If it's not too much trouble, would you be able to adjust the snippet with your suggestion?

Comment: Yes, it works great now! Thanks so much for the additional assistance.